# Erro Array to string conversion in

Tags: php

Estou tendo um problema que não sei ao certo como resolver eu já tentei de diversas maneiras usando `implode`, `list` e `foreach` usando `extract`...

Sou iniciante na linguagem, programo há uns 2 meses ai é o seguinte eu tenho um *model* que faz a inserção dos dados do formulário contato no banco de dados, porém sempre apresenta o erro:

> ```
> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\manga_informatica\models\ModelsOutros.php on line 25
> ```

**Segue o código:**

```
require_once 'ModelsConn.php';
class ModelsOutros extends ModelsConn {

private $dados;

private function getDados(){
    return $this->dados;}
private function setDados($dados){
    $this->dados = $dados;}


public function enviarContato(array $dados){
    $this->setDados($dados);
    $this->limparDados();
    $this->conectar();

    $query = "INSERT INTO contato(nome, email, telefone, assunto, mensagem, data) VALUES 
    ($this->dados['nome'],$this->dados['email'],$this->dados['telefone'],$this->dados['assunto'],$this->dados['mensagem'],NOW())";
    $query_result = mysqli_query($this->conexao,$query);

    if(mysqli_insert_id($this->conexao)){
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-sucess' role='alert'>Mensagem do sistema: Seu contato foi enviado com sucesso.<br/>Entraremos em contato o mais rápido possível.</div>";
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-sucess' role='alert'>Mensagem do sistema: Erro sua mensagem não foi enviada.<br/>Contacte um administrador do sistema.</div>";
    }

}

public function limparDados(){
    $this->setDados(array_map('strip_tags',$this->getDados()));
    $this->setDados(array_map('trim',$this->getDados()));
    $this->setDados(preg_replace('/[áàãâä]/ui', 'a', $this->getDados()));
    $this->setDados(preg_replace('/[éèêë]/ui', 'e', $this->getDados()));
    $this->setDados(preg_replace('/[íìîï]/ui', 'i', $this->getDados()));
    $this->setDados(preg_replace('/[óòõôö]/ui', 'o', $this->getDados()));
    $this->setDados(preg_replace('/[úùûü]/ui', 'u', $this->getDados()));
    $this->setDados(preg_replace('/[!#%&*]/ui', '', $this->getDados()));
}
}
```

Comment: hmm 'linha 5' ano ajuda no contexto, qual seria a linha exata?

Comment: a linha 5 do código é apenas um get para a manipulação dos dados, a linha que apresenta o erro no caso é a 25 onde ta escrita a query.